# What is the length of the anti-diagonal permutation in the centralizer of that element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$. Write the transposition $\sigma_i := (i, i+1)$.  In case $n = 2m$, write $$t = \sigma_m, ~~~s_i := \sigma_{m-i}\sigma_{m+i}~~ (1\leq i\leq m-1)$$ In case $n = 2m+1$, write $$t= \sigma_m\sigma_{m+1}\sigma_m,~~~s_i = \sigma_{m-i}\sigma_{m+i+1}~~~(1\leq i\leq m-1)$$

Now consider the element, $\alpha \in S_n$, represented by an $n \times n$ anti-diagonal matrix.  The elements $s_1,...,s_{m-1}, t$ generate the subgroup fixed by conjugation $$\sigma \mapsto \alpha^{-1} \sigma \alpha.$$  If $t_0 = t$, $t_i = s_i t_{i-1}s_i$, it is not difficult to see that $\alpha$ can be written as the product $\alpha = t_0t_1...t_{m-1}$.  Thus the "length" of $\alpha$ with respect to the elements $t, s_1,...,s_{m-1}$ is not greater than  $1 +3+5+...= m^2$.  Why is it precisely $m^2$? That is, why can't $\alpha$ be written as a shorter word in the elements $t,s_1,...,s_{m-1}$?

Comment: You can see that it must be about $m^2$ by counting the number of pairs of points $\{i,j\}$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$ that are reversed by $\sigma$ and by the generators. $n(n-1)/2$ such pairs are reversed by $\sigma$, whereas $2$ pairs are reversed by all but one of your generators, and $1$ or $3$ by $t$. But unfortunately that does not appear to give the exact answer.

Comment: Looks like it might be possible to use the length function in the group of signed permutation $C_2\wr S_m$. That is a Coxeter group and that could coome in handy. Well, Dirk Liebhold (+1) started thinking in the same direction...

Answer (score 3):

I only write the answer for the case of even $n$, but the odd case should work in a similar way.

What you have there is a Coxeter group of type B and its longest element. If you google that, I'm sure you will find information on why this longest element has exactly length $m^2$. For example, looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_element_of_a_Coxeter_group) Wikipedia page, we get

> If the Coxeter group is finite then the length of w0 is the number of the positive roots.

The number of positive roots is the same as the number of reflections, i.e. the number of conjugates of your generators $t$ and $s_i$ in your group. The set of conjugates of these generators is exactly
$$\{(i,j)(m-i,m-j) \mid 1 \leq i < j \leq m\} \cup \{(i,m-i) \mid 1 \leq i \leq m\}.$$

I'm not sure how much theory of Coxeter groups you need to answer your question, it might be possible to do it brutally by hand without using any of it. But if you are interested in these kinds of groups, I would suggest to look them up, the length of the longest element is one of the rather basic results you will find.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll do some reading then.